# Is it possible to sync a single file to s3?

Tags: amazon-s3

I'd like to sync a single file from my filesystem to s3.

Is this possible or can only directories by synced?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Use include/exclude options for the sync-directory command:

e.g. To sync just /var/local/path/filename.xyz to S3 use:

```
s3 sync /var/local/path s3://bucket/path --exclude='*' --include='*/filename.xyz'
```

Comment: For anyone using the AWS CLI on Windows, I had to use `"` instead of `'` otherwise it wouldn't work

Comment: should be: --include='filename.xyz' -

With the */ it also copies the files with the same name in subfolders

Comment: @Marina Your comment saved my day. The truth is that I don't know why sync is said to be recursive. Without putting "*/my-patter", it does not look for files in subdirectories.

Comment: Thanks for the answer (this works, however) could you update your answer to remove */ from the include statement above as noted by Marina

Comment: This works, but it appears --include will cause it to always copy the file, whether it is already in the destination or not.

Answer (score 16):

`cp` can be used to copy a single file to S3. If the filename already exists in the destination, this will replace it:

```
aws s3 cp local/path/to/file.js s3://bucket/path/to/file.js
```

Keep in mind that per the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-services-s3-commands.html#using-s3-commands-managing-objects-sync), `sync` will only make updates to the target if there have been file changes to the source file since the last run: `s3 sync updates any files that have a size or modified time that are different from files with the same name at the destination.` However, `cp` will always make updates to the target regardless of whether the source file has been modified.

Reference: [AWS CLI Command Reference: cp](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/s3/cp.html)

Comment: I assume this will cause identical files to be re-uploaded, no?

Comment: @user48956, unlike `sync`, `cp` doesn't check to see if the source file has a different modified datetime than a file with the same name at the destination before uploading. If you only want to re-upload when the source file has been modified, then sticking with `sync` will work. I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Just to comment on pythonjsgeo's answer. That seems to be the right solution but make sure so execute the command without the `=` symbol after the include and exclude tag. I was including the `=` symbol and getting weird behavior with the sync command.

```
s3 sync /var/local/path s3://bucket/path --exclude '*' --include '*/filename.xyz'
```

Answer (score -1):

You can mount S3 bucket as a local folder (using [RioFS](https://github.com/skoobe/riofs), for example) and then use your favorite tool to synchronize file(-s) or directories.